# A shell script with a for loop and an "array"

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

How can I use this sh script with for loop and an "array".
I would like to call the domains with a `for loop` inside the `if`.
Example:

```sh
for domain in $DOMAINS
do
  printf '%s\n' "$domain"
done
```

So if you add that under if then the `printf` should be like what?
For example, the `wlstop` I would like to be called where the `printf` is with `wls wlstop $domain`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/sh

ENV=$1
DOMAINS="1 2 3"

wls (){
    echo "$0 : $1 -v -d $2" 
    $1 -v -d $2
}

remove (){
    echo "$0 : Removing /domains/$1/servers/*" 
    set -x
    rm -rf /domains/$1/servers/*
    set +x
}

echo "$0 : Running wlsfullclean for $ENV"

if [ "$ENV" = "Utv" ]; then

    #Stop domain
    wls wlsstop 1   
    wls wlsstop 2
    wls wlsstop 3

    #Remove content in servers folder
    remove 1
    remove 2
    remove 3

    #wlsclean
    wls wlsclean 1
    wls wlsclean 2
    wls wlsclean 3

    #wlscfi
    wls wlscfi 1
    wls wlscfi 2
    wls wlscfi 3

    #Start server
    wls wlsstart 1
    wls wlsstart 2
    wls wlsstart 3

elif [ "$ENVI" = "Prod" ]; then
    echo "Prod"
fi
```

Comment: nothing wrong found so far, just replace your printf stuff with actual commands.

Answer (score 3):

```
if    [ Utv = "$ENV" ]
then  for  domain in 1 2 3
      do   for   wls in  stop clean cfi start
           do    wls wls"$wls" "$domain"
                 [ stop != "$wls" ] ||
                 remove "$domain"
           done
      done
fi
```

The `in ...` field is an array assignment. You assign the loop's iterators there. You can use a preset array, or you can just build one in as I do here. It really does not make sense to go to the trouble of assigning some shell variable for the sole purpose of assigning a `for` loop array - its twice the work, and not as easy to keep track of. That is my just my opinion though, of course.

Anyway, the `in ...` field is actually optional, because there is a preset array that the `for` loop will default to using anyway - the shell's arg array. It is for this reason that I believe this kind of stuff makes more sense in a shell function.

```
 wls_lp(){
     for  wls  in     stop clean cfi start
     do   for  domain
          do          set -x -- "-${-:--}" ${-:+"--"} "$@"
                      wls "wls$wls"  "$domain"
                      [ stop != "$wls" ] ||
                      remove "$domain"
                      { set +x "$@"; } 2>/dev/null
     done;done 
}
```

If you put that function in your script you can just run the whole loop over a list of domains like:

```
if     [ Utv = "$ENV" ] 
then   wls_lp domain1 domain2 domain3
fi
```

Comment: wlsclean: ERROR: Not a valid domain: 1

Comment: @user1423277 - well, the best I can do is work with the values you provide - and `1`, `2`, and `3` are the three characters assigned to `$DOMAINS` in your script. What else can I do? At the very least your error message suggest `wlsclean` is *running*.

Comment: for  domain in $DOMAINS works

Comment: @user1423277 - then you must have copied something wrong - either out of this answer out of this answer or into your question. what is different about the 1 used here and the `wls wlsclean 1` you do in your script? can you edit the shebang to read `/bin/sh -x` and have a look at what goes on? or do you have any other clue? this should just work

Comment: i wonder if its the order? in your script you do it opposite: `for wls in stop clean cfi start; do for domain in 1 2 3; do wls wls"$wls" "$domain"; [ stop != "$wls" ] || remove "$domain"; done; done`

Comment: well all I know is that it says wlsstop, wlsclean....... ERROR: Not a valid domain if I use the 1 2 3. But if I change to $Domains it works.

for  domain in $DOMAINS
      do   for   wls in  stop clean cfi start
           do    wls wls"$wls" "$domain"
                 [ stop != "$wls" ] ||
                 remove "$domain"
           done
      done

Comment: @user1423277 - when you say it works - does it actually *do* anything? If `$DOMAINS` is not set then the `for` loop will do nothing. did you try the `/usr/bin/sh -x` thing?

Comment: Well the 1 2 3 are actually real domain names. I just changed it in this page so you cant see what the names are. And it really do work by doing it with $Domains. So I guess my bad....your way would also work if I change the 1 2 3 to the real names. I thought it was the number in the "array". So all good. :-)

Comment: @user1423277 - yeah, that makes sense. see the edit here. sorry it was so terse before. and what are you trying to print exactly?

Comment: Well I just want the script to be as small as possible to be able to run all wls commands and maybe print out what happens.

Comment: @user1423277 - there you go. try that out.

Comment: Stop went good but scfi went + wls wlsclean -h
/proj/vobs/main/tool/wlsfullclean.sh : wlsclean -v -d -h
wlsclean: ERROR: Not a valid domain: -h

Comment: @user1423277 - how come? you should be able to see whats going on when it errors out. if the `$DOMAINS` thing was working before you can use `wls_lp $DOMAINS` probably.

Comment: Hmm strange. I use exactly what you have except in domain1 domain2 and domain 3 I send in my real domain. Where does it get the -h from?

All servers stopped: xxxxx, xxxxxx
+ [ stop != stop ]
+ 2> /dev/null
+ wls wlsclean -h
/proj/main/tool/wlsfullclean.sh : wlsclean -v -d -h
wlsclean: ERROR: Not a valid domain: -h

Comment: @user1423277 - youre definitely defining the function right? I mean `wls_lp()` is used? if there is a whites space issue or something it could be a problem. I'll wrap it in braces. you have to make sure that functions gets defined and you dont just run the `for` loop in the main shell context. a function gets its own set of positional parameters - its own arg array - but if you run the for loop in the main body of the script that wont be true and it will use `"$1"` and so on from the scripts positional parameters.

Comment: @user1423277 - no, i get it. i was clearing out the for loop's array by trying to preserve the positional parameters. its fixed now. usually that stuff doesnt matter because the array is only set once, but this is an inner loop and so it has to set the `$domain` array to the positional parameters for every `$wls` iteration. when i dump the positionals in the first go round the next `$wls` screws up. it works fine now.

Comment: hehe. I just also found out that it was the set row that did something wrong. I will try this.

Comment: @user1423277 - you're welcome. i'm totallly done with it, but i did do one more edit though. i added `${-:+"--"}` which just protects your array in case any `$domain` happens to begin with either a `+` or a `-` and keeps the shell from possibly misinterpreting the argument. you should add it. have fun with it.